# Luminosity of the Milky Way compared to Seyfert galaxies

Tags: galaxy, milky-way, luminosity, seyfert-galaxy

[This page](http://www.astro.utu.fi/%7Ecflynn/galdyn/intro_mw.html) lists the total luminosity of the Milky Way (MW) Galaxy to be $4\times10^{10}$ $L_{\rm sol}$, and $L_{\rm sol}=3.86 \cdot 10^{33} {\rm ergs.sec}^{-1}$; this gives a total luminosity for the MW of $1.54\cdot 10^{44}{\rm ergs.sec}^{-1}$.

But [Seyfert galaxies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seyfert_galaxy) can have luminosities of $\sim 10^{40} - 10^{42}{\rm ergs.sec}^{-1}$, and this is due to the high luminosity of the galactic core of a Seyfert.

Since the MW doesn't have an active SMBH, does this mean that the MW is particularly bright due to a high luminosity stellar population? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Seyferts can easily be as or more luminous than the Milky Way.

Comment: Yeah, I know, and that's my point; shouldn't the MW be less luminous than Seyferts? Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: So what you may have missed is a reliable source of Seyfert luminosities, since I don't recognise your range.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seyfert_galaxy) says that "Seyfert galaxies  [...] luminosities ranging between $10^8$ and $10^{11}$ solar luminosities." not quite the range stated in the question - what am I missing?